# Flash loop error want to continue no idea how

Tags: flash, loops

I have a flash loop with a function inside (nothing special, just looks through some text files on hard drive).  However, some of the files don't satisfy, this is expected and the program throws an error as expected.  No surprises there.

But!  I would like it to move on to the next text file when it finds a bad text file.  Instead, it just stops everything.  How can I make it continue on?

The errors are:
Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. 
text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: file:

Comment: If you have fixed the problem, why not post your solution as an answer to your own question? It's one way to contribute to the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(...)
{
  try
  {
    //do stuff
  }
  catch(e:Error)
  {
    continue;
    //not really necessary after having caught the error
    //but if you need to have more code after the catch statement
    //you may want to call continue;
  }
}
```